# How to integrate SDK in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, reward

I own a reward app and the dev of the app has abandon the project.
So im alone in this and i dont know how to integrate 2 advertising networks into my app...They share the SDK for monetization and i must put it in the android studio and make build the apk again to update it in google play.
I cant figure out how to do it..I would like to use their offerwall only.
if it seems hard to understand pls tell me to send the info you need.if it is simpler to do it someone for me i have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to take someone else's code, which they worked hard on. You then want to change the advertising network id so you get the money. You then want to upload the result to Google Play. This sounds an awful lot like stealing someone else's work. I'm not going to help you with this, and I doubt anyone else will on Stack Overflow either.

Comment: look, i bought the code of the reward app from a well known site and i have the rights to use it of course.The dev make some changes in the code for me and he implement some ad networks..the problem is that ignores me for about 1 month and i just want to integrate 2 more networks..so i ask for help..Is that so bad?I didnt steal someone work..He sold me his work via a site but i need better support...